# How can I send a file and a string to web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, upload

I created a file upload service (asp.net) with simultaneous entry of the user name that inserts the file (as per the code below), now I have to create a `C#` client to upload the file, can you help me?

```
        public class FIleUploadAPI
        {
            public IFormFile files { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> Post(FIleUploadAPI files, string nu)
        {
            if (files.files.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "/uploads/"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "uploads");
                    }
                    using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create(files.files.FileName))
                    {
                        files.files.CopyTo(filestream);
                        filestream.Flush();
                        string[] pht = files.files.FileName.Split(".");
                        filestream.Close();
                        if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "/uploads/"))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "uploads/" + nu);
                        }
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        System.IO.File.Move(files.files.FileName, @"uploads/" + nu + "/" + pht[0] + "_" + now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + "." + pht[1]);
                        return "/uploads/" + nu + "/" + pht[0] + "_" + now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + "." + pht[1];
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Unsuccessful";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please describe what is not working, `I have to create a C # client to upload the file, can you help me?` is not an issue we can help with here, it is too broad. Are there error's you are seeing, what *isn't* working, what is the expected output/behaviour?

Comment: I would suggest to overlook your naming of classes, properties etc. If the naming does not clearly suggest it's purpose it creates confusion for yourself and others trying to understand your code and it's purpose.

Comment: You need to pass file along with string? or file is getting in web api but string is not passing along with file? Please elaborate your exact issue.

Comment: I have to pass the string along with the file, sorry if I answered only now.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route(UploadFile)]
        public async Task<string> Post(IFormFile files, string nu)
        {
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "/uploads/"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "uploads");
                    }
                    using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create(files.FileName))
                    {
                        files.CopyTo(filestream);
                        filestream.Flush();
                        string[] pht = files.FileName.Split(".");
                        filestream.Close();
                        if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "/uploads/"))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "uploads/" + nu);
                        }
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        System.IO.File.Move(files.FileName, @"uploads/" + nu + "/" + pht[0] + "_" + now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + "." + pht[1]);
                        return "/uploads/" + nu + "/" + pht[0] + "_" + now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss") + "." + pht[1];
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Unsuccessful";
            }

        }`enter code h


var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0];
formData.append('FileUpload', file);

$.ajax({
    url: "/controllername/UploadFile? nu=" + "mystring",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function (result) {
    },

    error: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: Please update your post to include an explanation of your proposed solution. Currently it doesn't explain what it does, by providing an explanation it would help the OP understand and anyone else that may come across this solution; please format your post as well.

Comment: @Sridhar R
not understanding that libraries should be used and what this code actually does I can't understand how it works, it gives me a lot of errors

Comment: I entered your code, but it doesn't find FormData() and document.getElementById and $.ajax

Comment: FormData  is jquery feature , I have used this above code I can able to upload the file . <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" />                   var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0];
formData.append('FileUpload', file);